# CSS: drop down menu not selecting correctly; margin spacing?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a drop down menu and when you hover over an option it shows the submenu, but then when you move the cursor down; sometimes the rest of the menu will hide. I have noticed there is a little bit of space (margin? border?) underneath that I am assuming is the culprit unless someone can tell me differently.

Below is an image to show what I mean; there is a small gap between the two options and I am assuming when you make the cursor go over that point it comes off "hover" and hides it

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
.menu ul { margin = ..;}
```

The above code makes the margin bigger, however even when it is set to 0 it still seems to be there..

This is my HTML for the menu

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#666666">
          <div class="menu" align="center">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/barequipment" class="dropmenutext">Bar Equipment</a>
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="/barequipment/tills">Tills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/barequipment/furniture">Bar Furniture</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/barequipment/sundries">Bar Sundries</a></li>
       ...         
    </div></td>
```

This is the Css for the menu class

```
 @charset "utf-8";

    * {
      margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  
    }

    .menu {
    margin: 0px;    
    text-align: center;  
    background: #efefef;  
    padding: 0px;
    }

    .menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    .menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;    
}

.menu ul {
    background: #efefef;    
    padding: 0;              
    list-style: none;      
    position: relative;    
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 0px;
}
.menu ul:after {
    content: "";     
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}

.menu ul li {
    float: left;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
    background: #999;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px;
    color: #757575;
    text-decoration:none;               
}

.menu ul ul {
    background: #efefef;
    padding: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;    /* ?? */
}
.menu ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 0px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 0px solid pink; 
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color:#fff;
    display: block; 
}   

.menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: red;    
}

.menu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 0px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 0px solid pink; 
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu ul ul ul li a:hover {
    background: red;    */
} 

.menu ul ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you experiencing the issue on? Couldn't replicate on Firefox.

Comment: I was using it on google chrome, I have just checked firefox and it is also there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p1kuzzdo/

try this css:

```
 @charset "utf-8";

    * {
      margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  
    }

   .menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #efefef;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

    .menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    .menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;    
}

.menu ul {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu ul:after {
    content: "";     
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}


.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
    background: #999;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
.menu ul li a {
    color: #757575;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #efefef;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
.menu ul ul li {
    border-bottom: 0 solid pink;
    border-top: 0 solid #6b727c;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color:#fff;
    display: block; 
}   

.menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: red;    
}

.menu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 0px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 0px solid pink; 
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul ul ul li a {

    color: #fff;
}

.menu ul ul ul li a:hover {
    background: red;    */
} 

.menu ul ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: .menu ul ul li a{ padding: 0 10px;}

Comment: Definitely needed that extra bit of code, edited this code to put my colours and backgrounds etc back in, but this solution worked, Thanks!